# Libgdx | Box2d | Create circle from PolygonShape

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I want to create a circle from a `PolygonShape`, that way I can rotate the circle (as far as I know, you cannot rotate a `CircleShape`).

Does anyone have some insight on generating the vertices? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using the radius from `PolygonShape`? `PolygonShape.radius` don't work for you?

Comment: How would I set the position?

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamic Bodies](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d#dynamic-bodies).